# Filter successive values from a list

Tags: r

I have a list with certain sheet names:

```
   sheet_names <- c("Sheet_Amsterdam", "Sheet_Amsterdam_sub", "Sheet_Rotterdam", "Sheet_Rotterdam_sub")
```

Now I would like to write a for loop in which I want to perform a function for the: 
-1st en 2nd element
-3rd and 4th element

etc... First I think I should filter them. So result should look like this:

```
        Name1               Name2
1     Sheet_Amsterdam     Sheet_Rotterdam
2 Sheet_Amsterdam_sub Sheet_Rotterdam_sub
```

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

```
dim(sheet_names) <- c(2, 2)
colnames(sheet_names) <- paste0("Name", 1:2)
```

This will reformat your vector into a 2x2 matrix. I'm not sure what you want to do with it afterwards though.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear whether the 'vector' needs to converted to 'data.frame' based on the position of the elements in the 'vector' or based on patterns in it.  (Also, the `filter` part is confusing.  I didn't find any elements left out in the desired output.)  If it is the former, we could convert the 'sheet_names' to `matrix` by specifying the `ncol` and the `dimnames` as a `list` and then we wrap it to `data.frame` by `as.data.frame`.

```
 as.data.frame(matrix(sheet_names, ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL,
               paste0('Name', 1:2))))
 #                Name1               Name2
 #1     Sheet_Amsterdam     Sheet_Rotterdam
 #2 Sheet_Amsterdam_sub Sheet_Rotterdam_sub
```

---

If you want to group the 'sheet_names' based on the prefix part

```
  r1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,split(sheet_names,
                           sub('_sub', '', sheet_names))))
  colnames(r1) <- paste0('Name', 1:2)
  r1
  #                Name1               Name2
  #1     Sheet_Amsterdam     Sheet_Rotterdam
  #2 Sheet_Amsterdam_sub Sheet_Rotterdam_sub
```

In this case, we are removing the suffix '_sub' from the 'sheet_names' using `regex` (`sub('_sub', ..`) and use that as a grouping variable to `split` the 'sheet_names'.  The result will be a `list`, which we convert to `matrix` (`do.call(cbind,`) and wrap it with `as.data.frame` to convert back to `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to call a function with each pair of the values, you can use `tapply`. `INDEX` groups the elements in `X` and `FUN` is called with each group of elements:

```
sheet_names <- c("Sheet_Amsterdam", "Sheet_Amsterdam_sub", "Sheet_Rotterdam", "Sheet_Rotterdam_sub")

tapply(X = sheet_names,
       INDEX = rep(1:2, each = 2),
       FUN = print)
# [1] "Sheet_Amsterdam"     "Sheet_Amsterdam_sub"
# [1] "Sheet_Rotterdam"     "Sheet_Rotterdam_sub"
```